# How to get value form name[] of textbox [script]

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

my html code

```
<html>
    <form name='form1' method='post' action='add.php' onsubmit='return fnSubmit();'>
    <div id='textfield'>
       <div>
          <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name1' size = '50'>
       </div>
       <div>
          <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name2' size = '50'>
       </div>
       <div>
          <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name3' size = '50'>
       </div>
       <div>
          <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name4' size = '50'>
       </div>
       <div>
          <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name5' size = '50'>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type='submit' value='sendvalue'>
    <input type='button' value='+' id='submit1'>
    </div>
    </form>
    </html>
```

script for check null textbox if null alert and focus that textbox

```
 <script language='javascript'>
       function fnSubmit(){
        if(document.form1.name[].value == "")   {
                    alert("please enter value");
            document.form1.name[].focus();
            return false;
        }
    document.form1.submit();
    }   
    </script>
```

but it doesn't work array

i use add textbox with button

i have problem to use id for autocomplete search

Comment: Unsure what you want. Please give more detail including what you've tried and and bug testing results that that produced

Comment: `<input type="text" [...] required />` Done.

Answer (score 0):

PS: use the [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute instead. Then on form submissions search for all required elements and loop over the fields

```js
   function fnSubmit() {
     var requiredNodes = document.querySelectorAll("form[name=form1] [required]");
     for(var i = 0; i < requiredNodes.length; i++){
       if (!requiredNodes[i].value) {
         alert("please enter value");
         requiredNodes[i].focus();
         return false;
       }
     }
     document.form1.submit();
   }
```

```html
<form name='form1' method='post' action='add.php' onsubmit='return fnSubmit();'>
<div id='textfield'>
   <div>
      <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name1' size = '50' required>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name2' size = '50' required>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name3' size = '50' required>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name4' size = '50' required>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type='text' name = 'name[]' id = 'name5' size = '50' required>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
<input type='submit' value='sendvalue'>
<input type='button' value='+' id='submit1'>
</div>
</form>
```

The javascript code you have wrote is what browser dose by default now days if the [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute is present. So `fnSubmit` will not be any useful for newer browser or unless you turn of native form validation (with `novalidate` attribute) and you want to do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question verbatim, use this:

```
<form [...] onSubmit="return fnSubmit(this)">
```

And...

```
function fnSubmit(theForm) {
    var textboxes = theForm.getElementsByName("name[]"),
        l = textboxes.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( textboxes[i].value == "") {
            alert("Please enter value");
            textboxes[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, this is the "1990s" way of doing it. These days, you do:

```
<input type="text" [...] required />
```

And the browser will handle it for you, no JavaScript required.